# reset step counter value every day android

Tags: java, android

I made this android app which counts footsteps and that works well, but it can only reset the steps when the device has rebooted. I would like it to store the counted footsteps in the SharedPreferences prefs. Then reset it to zero every day, but i am not sure how to proceed. By running the reset() function it only sets the visual steps to zero.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  SensorEventListener {
SensorManager sensorManager;
TextView tv_steps;
boolean running = false;
SharedPreferences prefs = null;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
int steps;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv_steps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_steps);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();

}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    running = true;
    Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if(countSensor != null){
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sensor not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    running = false;
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    // unregistering register listener hardware counter is disabled
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
     if(running){
       steps = (int) event.values[0];
       editor.putInt("steps", steps);
       editor.commit();
       //  resetStepCount();
       tv_steps.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getInt("steps", steps)));

     }
}

private void resetStepCount() {
    //   reset every 24 hours.
    editor.clear();
    steps = 0;
    editor.putInt("steps", steps);
    editor.commit();

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)